# Why aren't the images displaying online when they work fine locally using laravel and angular?

Tags: php, angular, laravel

in this my site https://www.aswaktinghir.com/
I've created a website using `Laravel` and `Angular`, and I've successfully hosted it. I deleted the `storage` directory for the images and then ran the command `php artisan storage:link`. I created a storage directory within the `public` directory and uploaded the images, but the images are not displaying online. I'm not sure why. I inspected my page and copied the image link https://aswaktinghir.com/ecommb/public/storage/annonces/September2020/animaux.jpg and tried it in another browser, but it gives me a "Forbidden" error: "`You don't have permission to access this resource.`" I even tried running `chmod -R 775 storage`, but the problem persists. When I take this link and change [aswaktinghir.com](https://aswaktinghir.com) to `localhost`, the image displays correctly.

Comment: I see back slashes in your images path url. https://aswaktinghir.com/ecommb/public/storage/annonces\September2020\mariage.jpg - So you should find the issue in your related files.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I set up permissions for storage in production:

First make sure that you have your domain name in your .env file for the APP_URL.

Second, try this.

Install access control

- sudo apt install acl

Set permissions for storage

- sudo setfacl -Rm u:www-data:rwX,u:[YOUR USER]:rwX  storage/
- sudo setfacl -Rdm u:www-data:rwX,u:[YOUR USER]:rwX  storage/

Check permissions

- getfacl storage/

I did a whole course on putting Laravel projects in production but I made a gist with commands to run.

https://gist.github.com/designatedcoder/122694e1a5f73e17db3c7f11ee5f3562

Comment: Thanks for your help! My issue was resolved with support's assistance. I appreciate the guidance you provided—it was very insightful.